# Problema com while C++

Tags: c++

Estou começando a aprender programação em C++ e estou com problemas em resolver um exercício através de repetição. O exercício tem tal enunciado:

Faça um programa que leia 5 números inteiros. O programa deve então determinar se os números estão ou não ordenados (ordem crescente). Caso estejam ordenados, o programa deve escrever 1, caso contrário deve escrever 0.

Exemplo de entrada: 1 2 3 4 5
Saída: 1

Exemplo de entrada: 1 3 2 4 5
Saída: 0

Consegui resolver o problema com esse código, sem a utilização da função while:

```
#include  using namespace std;
```

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

`cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;

    if (num1<=num2 and num2<=num3 and num3<=num4 and num4<=num5)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}`

Porém, não sei como faria para resolvê-la com a função while e nem a lógica por detrás da utilização dessa função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> valores;       // Declara vetor de int

    for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)     // Grava 5 número no vetor valores
    {

        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;

        valores.push_back(temp);

    }

    for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)     //Executa a verificação
    {
        if(valores[k] > valores[k+1])   // Verifica a posição seguinte, se for maior, significa desordenado
        {
            return 0;   // Não ordenado

        }
    }

    return 1;   // Ordenado

}
```

Explicação em comentários no código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou utilizar a sua como base para tentar aperfeiçoar meu código!

Comment: Dispõe, colega.

Comment: @FourZeroFive não é aconselhável utilizar o main para retornar valores desse modo, já que se o main retorna 0 indica para o sistema que o chamou que ocorreu tudo bem e um retorno diferente de 0 indica que aconteceu algo fora do normal.